# [Flex AS4]Problem of Printing in Landscape Mode

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, printing, orientation

Well, I have a app writing in Flex AS4. Now I have a component and I need to print it using FlexPrintJob. However, every time when users need to print it in landscape mode, he/she has to click the "Properties" button in the dialog of print and change the orientation from portrait to landscape and it is really annoying.

I wander if there is a way to control it in programming? In other words, can I change some codes to set the default properties of printers to print it in landscape mode?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the print job to be set as landscape through the print settings, however, you can rotate the image you want to print:

```
var print:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();
print.printAsBitmap = true;
var bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.width, stage.height);
bitmap.draw(stage);
var image:Image = new Image();
image.source = bitmap;
image.rotation = 90;
print.addObject(image);
print.send();
print.start();
```

This is untested, but you get the idea.